# get date ranges from dynamic objects

Tags: c#, dynamic

I am using the line below to turn a json string into object like below. As can be seen that the object has a created at field, but as it gains more than one object I would like to get the created_at of the first `dynObj` and then  the created_at of the last `dynObj` so i have a date range what is the best method of doing this, I want to get the date range. this creates 200 objects.

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(timelineData)
```

Dynamic object

```
   {
        "created_at": "Fri Sep 27 02:00:08 +0000 2013",
        "id": ,
        "id_str": "",
        "text": "",
        "source": "<a href=\"http://adobe.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Adobe® Social</a>",
        "truncated": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "user": {

        },
        "geo": null,
        "coordinates": null,
        "place": null,
        "contributors": null,
        "retweet_count": 28,
        "favorite_count": 13,
        "entities": {
          "hashtags": [],
          "symbols": [],
          "urls": [],
          "user_mentions": [],
          "media": [
            {
            }
          ]
        },
        "favorited": false,
        "retweeted": false,
        "possibly_sensitive": false,
        "lang": "en"
      },
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Does `created_at` come back as a `DateTime` or a `string`?

Comment: If you have a collection of objects you could try using Linq's [`Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx) and [`Min`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min.aspx) functions

Comment: This is almost exactly the same question someone asked earlier today about getting Max and Min. You really should use that answer... http://stackoverflow.com/q/19052171/7495