# Quering a Dynamic Object List for Max and Min Values

Tags: c#, linq, object

I have the following code which returns the dynamic object. I would like to query them all and get the min date and max date, which is held in `created_at`. How would I query this?

Currently I am using a `foreach` loop, and doing comparisons and setting the dates. Is there a more efficient way to do this and how would I go about doing this? I know its linq but cant get my head around the concept of how to actually do it.

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Data);
{
    "created_at": "Fri Sep 27 02:00:08 +0000 2013",
    "id": 
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string Data = @"[{
    ""created_at"": ""Fri Sep 27 02:00:08 +0000 2013"",
    ""id"": 1
},
{
    ""created_at"": ""Sat Sep 28 02:00:08 +0000 2013"",
    ""id"": 1
}]";
IEnumerable<dynamic> d = (dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Data);
var dates = d.Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.created_at.ToString(),
    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss K yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .Cast<DateTime>().ToList();
var maxDate = dates.Max();
var minDate = dates.Min();
```

Answer (score 0):

your `dynObj` seems to be an array or list right?

you could use linq queries like

```
list.Min(p => DateTime.Parse(p.created_at));
```

Or instead of parsing the date in each iteration, simply convert the type of your created_at to a `DateTime`!